# "Allowed memory size" error when there's enough memory

Tags: php, memory-management, fastcgi

I have

PHP Fatal error: `Allowed memory size of 13241728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes)`

script (php) file is 400kb, output is 250kb

It opens (and unserializes) several files, each of them is no more then 8mb (total 32Mb).

For example:

```
while (($file = readdir($dir))!=false) {
$inf=file_get_contents($file);
$inf=unserialize($inf);
......
}
```

I'm using fast-cgi.

Why there's not enough memory when it should be enough?

I've been setting it in php.ini from 12Mb, 16, 32, 50 (same error) to 80Mb (wow it works)

Now it is set to `-1` but I want to figure out why this happens and how to solve it (maybe unset some vars or something)

Comment: Hi, Can you please paste some more code for a better understanding

Comment: It's not the outputsize, nor the script size. It's the size of the files you try to load, plus overhead, plus the size the unserialized array takes

Comment: @Aman Chhabra the code is about 400kb I don't which part to show

Comment: @Martijn you're right, and I want to find where it takes so many data, when there's no data should be

Comment: You can add this in your loop, with some calculations you could find the bad guy: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php

Comment: thanx for `memory-get-usage` hint. I think I found where it grows from in my code. If you set your comment as answer I'll confirm it

Answer (score 1):

this is because php doesn t know how to properly unserialize $inf .

it's looping in a infinite way .

What is in the file you re trying to get ?

i think this is because you trying to save the unserialized variable into itself .

unserialize is recurisve ...

so you should do :

```
  $variable = unserialize ( $inf );
```

instead of

```
  $inf = unserialize ( $inf );
```

official php doc : http://php.net/unserialize

Comment: do you mean `$inf`=unserialize(`$inf`) loops into itself? )))

Comment: yes :) , i had last week the same problem trying to serialize / unserialize object in php

Comment: i m sorry i don t see how to help you

Comment: I've found already. There was strange unserializing of one file. On my win32 php it was 16Mb after unserialize(), on server it was 60Mb.

Comment: from my experience serializing / unserializing should be only used for array or simple object ... because it takes a lot of process time and memory , i have no idea what you project is about but , you may try something different, in order to optimize your process ...